# Can a C# custom attribute be evaluated at compile time?

Tags: c#, .net, metaprogramming, custom-attributes

I have the following custom attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = false)]
sealed public class CLSASafeAttribute : Attribute
{
    public Boolean CLSSafe { get; set; }
    public CLSASafeAttribute(Boolean safe)
    {
        CLSSafe = safe;
    }
}
```

And the following enum in part:

```
public enum BaseTypes
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Base class.
    /// </summary>
    [CLSASafe(true)]
    Object = 0,

    /// <summary>
    /// True / false.
    /// </summary>
    [CLSASafe(true)]
    Boolean,

    /// <summary>
    /// Signed 8 bit integer.
    /// </summary>
    [CLSASafe(false)]
    Int8
}
```

I now want to be able to create a unique class for each enum, and be able to mark it as CLSSafe by looking at the type being implemented. I have the following, which is clearly incorrect, but illustrates my intention:

```
[CLSASafe((Boolean)typeof(BaseTypes.Object).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(BaseTypes.Object), false))]
sealed public class BaseObject : Field
{
    public Object Value;
}
```

Is there a way of doing this (apart from manually marking the signatures)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to define your attribute as follows:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = false)]
sealed public class CLSASafeAttribute : Attribute {
    public CLSASafeAttribute(Boolean safe) {
        CLSSafe = safe;
    }
    public CLSASafeAttribute(BaseTypes type) {
        CLSSafe = IsCLSSafe(type);
    }
    public Boolean CLSSafe {
        get;
        private set;
    }
    public static bool IsCLSSafe(BaseTypes type) {
        var fieldInfo = typeof(BaseTypes).GetField(typeof(BaseTypes).GetEnumName(type));
        var attributes = fieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CLSASafeAttribute), false);
        return (attributes.Length > 0) && ((CLSASafeAttribute)attributes[0]).CLSSafe;
    }
}
```

Then, it will be possible to use the following declarations:

```
class Foo {
    [CLSASafe(BaseTypes.Object)] // CLSSafe = true
    object someField1;
    [CLSASafe(BaseTypes.Boolean)] // CLSSafe = true
    bool someField2;
    [CLSASafe(BaseTypes.Int8)] // CLSSafe = false
    byte someField3;
}
```

Or, anyway to determine whether the specific field is safe or not:

```
BaseTypes baseType = GetBaseType(...type of specific field ...);
bool isCLSSafe = CLSASafeAttribute.IsCLSSafe(baseType);
```

Comment: Wow, thank you very much! You clearly know your attributes well!